# Elastic beanstalk Django POST: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, csrf, gunicorn

I can't pass the CSRF verification neither FORM-POST nor AJAX-POST. but it works when testing in local machine or `DEBUG=True`.

This is what I use for my django application:

- Django==1.9.2
- django-allauth==0.25.2
- django-redis-sessions==0.5.0
- gunicorn==19.4.5
- AWS elasticbeanstalk single docker
- Configured AWS elasticbeanstalk load balancer which accepts both http and https request

and `settings.py`:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

also, I've used `render(), {% csrf_token %}` for rendering response.

I configured all resources as correctly as I can. but still got `CSRF verification failed`...

**EDIT**
After tons of tries, I found abnormal behavior: `{% csrf_token %}` value refreshed every single request. I have no idea why it happened.

for instance,

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'www:article' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subtitle" name="subtitle">
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit">
</form>

1st request
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='66Z1Xq1tHReWIkK86dx780L8LPqnuLec' />
2nd request
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='zw9HKIO7Pv9TpA5Ru4SlbwqA65sAe8NH' />
3rd request
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='wMznTwwELz5F8WmBQIg5pBAezdNdN3xV' />
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

When you put on your template `{% csrf_token %}` django create `<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='CMVhN4HQ2Uke6Dg9ytQDFSIAsLjnEAaL' />`, that is normal. Return on your question, do you try put `{% csrf_token %}` inside th form?

Comment: Oh sorry. `{% csrf_token %}` is really what I did. `<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='CMVhN4HQ2Uke6Dg9ytQDFSIAsLjnEAaL' />` is just a demonstration.